# CMD python is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to run my code by typing 'python name.py' in the CMD but it says:
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You haven't installed python correctly then. You'll need to add the interpreter to your path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have typed `py name.py` instead `python name.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the path to your python executable folder in the enviroment variables just search for enviroment variables and add the path ..

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall python on your machine and check add to path.

Or see how to add to your path according to another answer that already exists here in the forum:

[How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)